# Como criar uma base de dados automaticamente no Laravel com todas as tabelas?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, sqlite, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Bem eu preciso de ajuda em um problema, estou desenvolvendo um sistema pela primeira vez em laravel e eu precisaria criar uma base de dados para cada usuário cadastrado no meu sistema, essas base devem ter as mesmas tabelas eu já descobri com alternar a consulta para cada base mas não sei como criar uma base nova já com todas as tabelas automaticamente, já tenho a base com os usuários e nessa base vou guardar qual a base de dados de cada usuário nessa base dos usuários, eu estou usando **sqlite** atualmente durante o desenvolvimento. Por favor alguém me ajude ou me explique se tenho que fazer de outra maneira. E se possível gostaria de saber com executar migrate em todas as base ou em varias de uma vez.

Comment: Acho que podes começar por perceber bem o que queres: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDNYywKZ6jc

Comment: perfeito esse vídeo cara ajudou muito

Comment: Parece um requisito bem fora do comum, verifique se não está passando pelo caso do  ["problema xy"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)

Answer (score 1):

Espero ajudar:
Toda a documentação do Laravel se encontra aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation
Para criar migration, utilize o seguinte comando:

```
php artisan make:migration create_nomedatabela_table
```

Ao criar a migration, você vai notar que será criado as funções up() e down().
Na função up(), você colocará os campos da tabela. Abaixo um pequeno exemplo:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Depois de todas as migrations criadas, para rodá-las use:

```
php artisan migrate
```

A documentação do laravel referente a migrations está aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

==============================================================================
Uma maneira interessante de você realizar migration de forma automática é utilizando este pacote do [Xethron/migrations-generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator)

Para instalar o pacote use o comando:

```
composer require --dev "xethron/migrations-generator"
```

Depois cole essas linhas de códigos no arquivo `config/app.php`:

```
Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class,
Xethron\MigrationsGenerator\MigrationsGeneratorServiceProvider::class,
```

Como utilizar:

Você cria suas tabelas no seu banco de dados, conforme você está acostumado, e depois executa os comandos;

a) para criar TODAS as tabelas do banco:

```
php artisan help migrate:generate
```

b) Para criar tabelas específicas:

```
php artisan migrate:generate table1,table2,table3,table4,table5
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço

Comment: vlw cara mas n é exatamente o que eu queria